# no funciona el router en mi mini app SPA - javascript vanilla

Tags: javascript, html, script, router, vanilla

espero que estén bien... estoy tratando de recrear una mini SPA con javascript puro, no es nada compleja, lo estoy haciendo a modo de practica porque apenas ando aprendiendo, resulta que al momento de generar el enrutamiento de las paginas al presionar uno de los botones del menú me sale el siguiente error (no entiendo que está mal en mi codigo):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

esto es lo que tengo en mi archivo route.js:

```
const route = (event) => {
    event = event || window.event;
    event.preventDefault();
    window.history.pushState({}, "", event.target.href);
    handleLocation();
};

const routes = {
    404: "/pages/404.html",
    "/": "/pages/index.html",
    "/about": "/pages/about.html",
    "/lorem": "/pages/lorem.html",
};

const handleLocation = async () => {
    const path = window.location.pathname;
    const route = routes[path] || routes[404];
    const html = await fetch(route).then((data) => data.text());
    document.getElementById("main-page").innerHTML = html;
};

window.onpopstate = handleLocation;
window.route = route;

handleLocation();
```

y este es el index en donde quiero aplicar el router:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Vanilla SPA Router</title>
            <meta charset="UTF-8" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" />
            <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@6.5.95/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        </head>
    
        <body>
            <div id="root">
                <nav id="main-nav" class="sidebar">
                    <a href="/" onclick="route()">Home</a>
                    <a href="/about" onclick="route()">About</a>
                    <a href="/lorem" onclick="route()">Lorem</a>
                </nav>
//en este div es donde quiero aplicar el route, donde se almacenan el contenido de las otras paginas:
                <div id="main-page"></div>
            </div>
    
            <script src="js/router.js"></script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

esta sería la estructura del proyecto, pego una captura para que puedan notar como tengo guardado los archivos:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Nota:** el index que esta afuera de la carpeta pages es el mismo donde aplico el router, osea el que tiene el codigo que escribí más arriba, el otro index que está dentro de la carpeta pages es el home, pertenece a las paginas que quiero que su contenido aparezcan al lado del menú gracias al router

Agradezco cualquier info u ayuda que me puedan brindar amigos

Comment: Has mirado lo que te aparece en la consola del navegador? En la pestaña de red deberías ver la petición `fetch` y la respuesta

Comment: Se me ocurre que quizá la URL deba tener el directorio `vanilla_spa_router` en la dirección

Comment: gracias por las respuestas amigos, revisando y probando me di cuenta que el settings.json se esta creando fuera de la carpeta del proyecto, solo la incluí adentro y listo las rutas me funcionan